# How can I use Jackson to parse JSON with variable object names?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, cadvisor

Google's cAdvisor API gives JSON output like this:

```
{
  /system.slice/docker-13b18253fa70d837e9707a1c28e45a3573e82751f964b66d7c4cbc2256abc266.scope: {},
  /system.slice/docker-747f797d19931b4ef33cda0c519f935b592a0b828d16b8cafc350568ab2c1d28.scope: {},
  /system.slice/docker-bf947bfabf61cd5168bd599162cf5f5c2ea2350eece1ded018faebf598f7ee5b.scope: {},
  /system.slice/docker-e8e02d508400438603151dd462ef036d59fada8239f66be8e64813880b59a77d.scope: {
    name: "/system.slice/docker-e8e02d508400438603151dd462ef036d59fada8239f66be8e64813880b59a77d.scope",
    aliases: [...],
    namespace: "docker",
    spec: {...},
    stats: [...]
  }
}
```

I would describe this as 4 same-typed JSON objects with variable/anonymous names, held in an anonymous object.

My first thought would just do something like `mapper.readValue(response, Containers.class)`, where:

```
public class Containers extends BaseJsonObject {
    @JsonProperty
    public List<Container> containerList;
}
```

and

```
public class Container extends BaseJsonObject {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty
    public String[] aliases;

    @JsonProperty
    private String namespace;

    @JsonProperty
    private String spec;

    @JsonProperty
    public Stats[] stats;
}
```

But all of the variations on this I can think of yield the same result:  some permutation of `com.xyz.Containers@45c7e403[containerList=<null>]` or `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "/system.slice/docker-13b18253fa70d837e9707a1c28e45a3573e82751f964b66d7c4cbc2256abc266.scope" (class com.xyz.Containers), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "containerList"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3d285d7e; line: 1, column: 97] (through reference chain: com.xyz.Containers["/system.slice/docker-13b18253fa70d837e9707a1c28e45a3573e82751f964b66d7c4cbc2256abc266.scope"])`, with `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY = false` .

I've tried:

- `mapper.readValue(response, Container[].class)`
- `mapper.readValue(response, Containers.class)`
- `mapper.readValues(jsonParser, Container.class)`

As well as the following configurations:

- `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`
- `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);`

How can I parse JSON objects with variable/anonymous names, held in a non-array?  What is this called?

Comment: I think you should parse this JSON to Map<String, Container>

Comment: I found the docs for "raw" data-binding shortly after posting; this works.  I'd still like to know what I was doing wrong here.

Comment: I think its becouse in this JSON you don't have list/array of objects. You have object with properties like " /system...." and values are objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the @JsonAnySetter annotation](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html) as follows and put the objects with variable names into a map of `Map<String, Container>`.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonVariableNames {

    static final String JSON = "{\n"
            + "  \"a\": {\n"
            + "    \"value\": \"1\"\n"
            + "  },\n"
            + "  \"b\": {\n"
            + "    \"value\": \"2\"\n"
            + "  },\n"
            + "  \"c\": {\n"
            + "    \"value\": \"3\"\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}";
    static class Value {
        private final String value;

        @JsonCreator
        Value(@JsonProperty("value") final String value) {this.value = value;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Value{" +
                    "value='" + value + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Values {
        private final Map<String, Value> values = new HashMap<>();

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setValue(final String property, final Value value) {
            values.put(property, value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Values{" +
                    "values=" + values +
                    '}';
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Values.class));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Values{values={a=Value{value='1'}, b=Value{value='2'}, c=Value{value='3'}}}
```